# How get the value from NSDictionary with JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

So I have this json

data: {
Thresh: {
id: 412,
key: "Thresh",
name: "Thresh",
title: "the Chain Warden"
},
Aatrox: {
id: 266,
key: "Aatrox",
name: "Aatrox",
title: "the Darkin Blade"
},
Tryndamere: {
id: 23,
key: "Tryndamere",
name: "Tryndamere",
title: "the Barbarian King"
}

I'm trying to get all "id", but the only way I can find is using

```
[myArray addObject:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.Aatrox.id"]];
```

I want to know if have a easy way to get all id's, like without need to put the name example "Aatrox", just "id" or "title".

Here the code that I use to get the json

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];


NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: Once you have dictionary data in NSArray then you can get all ids using NSArray * arrayIDs = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"id"];. I am not sur e wether your response is in NSArray format.

Comment: @Rob I don't have the control of the JSON, they give me link and that's all, I read something like the JSON it's not valid but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Rob I try this too but the keys continue, so I still need put the name to get the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON looks like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Thresh": {
            "id": 412,
            "key": "Thresh",
            "name": "Thresh",
            "title": "the Chain Warden"
        },
        "Aatrox": {
            "id": 266,
            "key": "Aatrox",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade"
        },
        "Tryndamere": {
            "id": 23,
            "key": "Tryndamere",
            "name": "Tryndamere",
            "title": "the Barbarian King"
        }
    }
}
```

If that's the case, then you can then grab the dictionary associated with the key of `data`, and then grab an array of all the  values in that dictionary (i.e. an array of those child dictionaries):

```
NSArray *values = [dictionary[@"data"] allValues];
```

And then grab the array of values associated with the `id` key in each of those dictionaries:

```
NSArray *ids = [values valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSString` class `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator` method to separate your `JSON` object to pieces of strings. After that you can use a for loop to get elements that you need.(This is such a nasty way, but accomplishes what you asked) **However**, I strongly recommend you to read `JSON` string as an object by using [Jastor](https://github.com/elado/jastor) like library and by creating your own objects. Maybe this way seems to be hard, but it will be safer than your implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I wil try use the Jastor, but if don't work I wil try the nasty way ><.

Answer (score 0):

Lets just say your JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Thresh": {
    "id": 412,
    "key": "Thresh",
    "name": "Thresh",
    "title": "the Chain Warden"
  },
  "Aatrox": {
    "id": 266,
    "key": "Aatrox",
    "name": "Aatrox",
    "title": "the Darkin Blade"
  },
  "Tryndamere": {
    "id": 23,
    "key": "Tryndamere",
    "name": "Tryndamere",
    "title": "the Barbarian King"
  }
}
```

and you parse it using

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

You can use KVC collection operations to get exactly what you want. First we need to convert your dictionary to an array of values. Since you don't care about the keys this is easy:

```
NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];
```

Now we want all the IDs so we need to use @distinctUnionOfObjects to get that:

```
NSArray *ids = [values valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.id"];
```

We can combine this into a single line if we want:

```
NSArray *ids = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"allValues.@distinctUnionOfObjects.id"];
```

You can read more about KVC collection operations here: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

I would also suggest using a higher level JSON parsing library such as RestKit.